# “I so far am” Vs. “I am so far”?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammar, adverbs

> - I **so far** am worried about what is going to happen tomorrow.
> - I am **so far** worried about what is going to happen tomorrow.

Are these two examples above grammatically correct and giving the same meaning?

Comment: Neither is idiomatic. What idea are you wanting to convey with **so far**?

Comment: Till the moment of the present time; Till now. I want to know if there any difference in meaning if we moved the adverb “so far” before or after the verb-be “am”? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: Your example sentences don't use the phrase idiomatically. See my answer.  **So far** isn't really used with future-looking statements, such as worrying about tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **So far**, all we have to go on is a bit of hair on the carpet. We may
>   never solve this crime.
>
> All we have to go on **so far** is a bit of hair on the carpet. We may
>   never solve this crime.
>
> All we have to go on  is a bit of hair on the carpet, **so far**. We may never solve this crime.

**so far** = up to this point in time.  That is, **up until now**.

It's not that we can't reference the future, but **so far** is used in conjunction with the recent past impinging upon the present:

> So far, I **have been** worrying about what is going to happen tomorrow. I
>   can't think about next week!

Comment: But i am making  “so far” in my sentences to modify the present state of “worry” even if being worried refers to the future. Till this moment i am worried. (About...)

Comment: Perhaps you will perceive the  temporal discord if you say it like this:  **Up until now, I am worried....*    That is not idiomatic use of either the tense or the phrase "up until now".

Comment: Could we correct it by saying: I have so far been worried about... ? @Tᴚoɯɐuo

Comment: The present perfect addresses the time issues, as I showed in my answer.   Some native speakers might find "have so far been worried" a little jarring stylistically, because **so far** interrupting **have been worried** is not as natural as other options; but it is grammatical.